# Is it halal for women to recite the Quran (loudly) in front of non-mahrams? (Shia view)

Tags: halal-haram, women, quran-recitation, men, non-mahram

Occasionally, it can be watched in some channels on the television where women recite the Qur'an (loudly). I was wondering it is permissible (halal) for men who are non-mahrams to hear their voices?

Or it is Haram (impermissible)? (Shia view please, albeit Sunni view will be appreciated too)

Comment: Is it halal for women to talk with men? The answer to this is the same as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think its nothing wrong when it recite words from Allah (swt). Remember rabiatul adawiyah? She recites the Quran with intentions to spread the words, so people will feel the words from Allah (swt). And she is consider one of the pirious women in Islam too. Well, if your intention is not good just for riya because you have a good voice and to lure men to sin and women to envious you I think is haram.
But if u do it, out of fear and loving Allah (swt), miss Allah (swt) so much, and to teach people... its permissible. But you go to understand Quran first.

Answer (score 0):

Not haram, but not recommended either. Women's rhythmic voice is appealing to men.

I really don't know how to explain this, you just have to be one to understand a hijabi women has a certain lure for *believing* men. Her voice is part of what makes her luring.

Can you tell me where doing such is important or vital? If it ever becomes vital then why not, but again I don't of any real example...

Comment: On the whole, your answer seems admirable, well done.

Comment: But regarding the last part of your answer as you asked "Can you tell me where doing such is important or vital?", I don't say that it is important or vital, actually I asked it because I rarely watch in some channels that there are women (in the programs of the channels) who are reciting Quran, so i would know if it is halal or haram for men to listen to that. Jazak Allah Khaira for your logical answer.

Answer (score -1):

Alhamdulillah Wasalatu Wasalamu'Ala Rasullalah Ama Ba'ad,

This is haram according to Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal Rahimullah. I fact a woman speaking in a beautiful voice is classed as haram by all the madhabs. If that's what she is doing by reciting the Qur'an it is completely haram without a doubt. Even if she's the most pious woman. Allah Aza Waa Jal at boundaries for the family of Nabi Sallallahu Alayhi Wasalam so logically speaking this boundary would also be placed for women in general. Listening to a woman's voice for pure entertainment is haram and opens the doors for major fitnah.